# CAAnimation without animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, caanimation

I am trying to switch view controllers in my app using CAAnimation. When I switch between these 2 particular view controllers I do not want any animation. Is this possible? If so, how would I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: That's too little details. Do you want to disable default UINavigationController pop/push navigation? Do you want to disable yout custom CAAnimation for specific UIViewController's subclasses? When and how is the CAAnimation invoked? Show us some code.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using UINavigationController at all. I want to use CAAnimation for ANY view that is switching. It is invoked by using Protocols like [self.reference changeView1ToView2]; etc...
I just need to know if there is a way to use CAAnimation to switch views without any animation whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the duration to 0:

```
BOOL shouldAnimate = // here you set your condition whether to animate or not
CFTimeInterval standartDuration = 1.0;

CAAnimation *animation = [CAAnimation animation];
animation.duration = shouldAnimate ? standartDuration : 0.0;
```

Comment: I know this isn't related to my question, but how would I switch view controllers using CAAnimation while completely releasing the old view controller?

Comment: You could set yourself as animation's delegate and then implement 'animationDidStop:finished:' and inside there release the view of hidden view controller